# How to image thumbnail in google picker?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, google-picker

I'm working with google picker.

But in picker view, the image thumbnail not showing. But I want to show the thumbnail in preview.
But I can't. I'm trying this:

**Here is my code:**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    var developerKey = "";
    var clientId = "";

    var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'];

    var pickerApiLoaded = false;
    var oauthToken;

    // Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
    function onApiLoad {
        gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
        gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
    });

    function onAuthApiLoad() {
        window.gapi.auth.authorize(
                {
                    'client_id': clientId,
                    'scope': scope,
                    'immediate': false
                },
                handleAuthResult);
    }

    function onPickerApiLoad() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
        createPicker();
    }

    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
            oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
            createPicker();
        }
    }

    function createPicker() {
        if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
            var view = new google.picker.DocsView().setParent('root').setIncludeFolders(true)
            var uploadView = new google.picker.DocsUploadView().setIncludeFolders(true);

            view.setMimeTypes('image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg');
            uploadView.setMimeTypes('image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg');

            var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
                    addView(view).
                    addView(uploadView).
                    setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
                    setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
                    setCallback(pickerCallback).
                    build();
            picker.setVisible(true);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.picker-dialog').css('z-index', 10002);
            }, 10);
        }
    }

    function pickerCallback(data) {
        if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
            var fileId = data.docs[0].id;
            alert('You select: ' + fileId);
        }
    }
</script>
```

**The picker select file modal showing like this:**

[image]

**But I want it like this:**
[image]

Comment: What are your scopes?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Ok I'll add full code.

Comment: I think this could be due to your scope. Can you try using `drive.readonly` instead of `drive.file`?

Comment: OK. It's working.
Can I please add a answer? Or please you add a answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to use the `drive.readonly` scope rather than `drive.file`.*

#### More Information:

As per the authorisation information from the OAuth consent screen, the `drive.file` scope will allow your application to:

> - View files from Google Drive that you have opened with this app or that are shared publicly
> - Save changes to files that you have opened with this app
> - Create new files in Google Drive using this app
> - View folders and their contents from Google Drive that you have opened with this app
> - Make changes to folders and their contents that you have opened with this app
> - Delete contents of folders that you have opened with this app

Whereas the `drive.readonly` scope allows your application to:

> - See your Google Drive files
> - Download your files
> - See the names and emails of people you share files with

The important differences here are that the `drive.file` scope limits your application to **files that have been created with** ***or*** **have already been opened with** the application. Without the `readonly` scope, the thumbnail information can not be retrieved.

Note: Obviously this does change the scope of what your application can do and this will be reflected in the OAuth consent screen shown to users.

Comment: In the list view it's even worse -- you get broken thumbnails, which is not a great look. The `drive.readonly` scope does fix this, but because it's a restricted scope it requires app verification and a security assessment. I'd prefer if that the picker just showed a generic image icon.